# How can I increase the size of /boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

My OS can't upgrade because there is no space in `/boot` 
I have a patch waiting to be installed since 20-June-2017, but
it can't since there is no space in boot device.

The default allocation of 500MB to `/boot` mountpoint during installation is inadequate and creates problems later on for lay-users. This default should be increased to 2GB at least.

```
# lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04

# df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          1930716        0   1930716   0% /dev
tmpfs                          390284     6348    383936   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 956819116 31447432 876744996   4% /
tmpfs                         1951408    54920   1896488   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         1951408        0   1951408   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      482922   462967         0 100% /boot
tmpfs                          390284       52    390232   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                     7575024   579824   6995200   8% /media/kray42/B292-FCF6


# du -hs /boot 
450M    /boot

# ls -al /boot
total 453680
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jun 23 17:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Jun 20 12:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1245512 Feb 20 19:10 abi-4.4.0-64-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1245512 Mar  3 23:55 abi-4.4.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1245659 Mar 22 21:41 abi-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1245659 Mar 24 20:50 abi-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1245659 Mar 31 22:44 abi-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1246246 Apr 20 17:32 abi-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1246312 Apr 27 23:54 abi-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1246311 May 18 03:39 abi-4.4.0-79-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1246311 Jun 14 17:54 abi-4.4.0-81-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190247 Feb 20 19:10 config-4.4.0-64-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190247 Mar  3 23:55 config-4.4.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190236 Mar 22 21:41 config-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190236 Mar 24 20:50 config-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190236 Mar 31 22:44 config-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190214 Apr 20 17:32 config-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190355 Apr 27 23:54 config-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190356 May 18 03:39 config-4.4.0-79-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190356 Jun 14 17:54 config-4.4.0-81-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Jun 20 12:20 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38933720 Feb 22 05:11 initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38938945 Mar  9 23:48 initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38937995 Mar 28 13:09 initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38941116 Mar 31 01:08 initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38945168 Apr 18 11:16 initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38938922 Apr 25 17:27 initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38938108 May 17 08:36 initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38940314 Jun  7 09:34 initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 38944655 Jun 20 12:20 initrd.img-4.4.0-81-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Aug 28  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  3883990 Feb 20 19:10 System.map-4.4.0-64-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3883990 Mar  3 23:55 System.map-4.4.0-66-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3882277 Mar 22 21:41 System.map-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3882277 Mar 24 20:50 System.map-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3882277 Mar 31 22:44 System.map-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3883390 Apr 20 17:32 System.map-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3882872 Apr 27 23:54 System.map-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3883279 May 18 03:39 System.map-4.4.0-79-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3883391 Jun 14 17:54 System.map-4.4.0-81-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7087152 Feb 20 19:10 vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7087024 Mar  3 23:55 vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7083344 Mar 22 21:41 vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7083344 Mar 24 20:50 vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7083248 Mar 31 22:44 vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7081872 Apr 20 17:32 vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7089552 Apr 27 23:54 vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7091696 May 18 03:39 vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7092784 Jun 14 17:54 vmlinuz-4.4.0-81-generic
#
```

Comment: I am not sure which default you mean. My experience is that the installer does not try to create a partition for `/boot`, only an ESP partition mounted on `/boot/efi`for a UEFI installation. Anyway, bug reports & other requests to devs should be made on Launchpad, not here. Delete some old kernels to make space: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](//askubuntu.com/q/89710)

Comment: If you edit your question to include `ls -al /boot`, and a screenshot of gparted I can take a look for you. Ping me at @heynnema when you've got it done.

Comment: `du -hs /boot` gives me 85 MiB. I don't see why you'd need more than 500 MiB. Maybe remove some old kernels and/or set up your system to remove them automatically when they're no longer needed.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the pointers. I have included the outputs from du and ls of /boot.  I will clear up space as suggested.
But still shouldnt that be done by Ubuntu instead of me. regards.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: You do not need to increase the size of boot.
Delete some old kernels to make space manually. see: [How do I free up more space in /boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/89710)? as suggested by @Zanna

This will solve the problem of the patch getting installed properly.
Best solution is to setup the system to automatically delete the old kernels.